# A fast way to compute $\int_{\partial D(0,1)} \frac{dz}{8z^3-1}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Compute
$$\int_{\partial D(0,1)} \frac{dz}{8z^3-1}.$$

The question is not difficult by applying Cauchy integral formula. However I am always frustrated at how long it takes to compute that kind of complex integral with a polynomial in the denominator.

1. First, you need to factorize a third degree polynomial which is usually non-trivial. In this case: $\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{4}$ and $\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{4}$.
2. Then you need to do a partial fraction decomposition to separate the first integral into 3 pieces and finally apply to each of them Cauchy integral formula.

All of this is quite cumbersome and computation-heavy. Isn't there a faster way to compute such an integral?

Comment: To begin with, I'm not sure I agree that the factorization isn't trivial, here it's just the third roots of unity all divided by two. Second, instead of doing a partial fraction decomposition in the second step I'd suggest you just compute the residues at each point using limits.

Comment: since all the residues are inside the unit disc you can go to infinity (use Cauchy to move the integral from $|z|=1$ to $|z|=R$ large) and easily find the integral by estimation - here it is zero since the integrand is $O(1/R^2)$ for large $R$ as $|dz|=R$

Comment: I haven't yet seen the residues theorem. I guess that is the faster way I'm expecting...

Comment: Or substitute $z=1/w$, and you get $\int\frac{w\,dw}{8-w^3}$ along the same contour, with a *regular* integrand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the complex function $$f(z):=\frac{1}{8z^3-1}.$$
Observe that $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus D(0,1)$, which implies that for $R\ge1$,
$$\int_{\partial D(0,1)} f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=\int_{\partial D(0,R)} f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z.$$
Furthermore note that by the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality) $\lvert f(Re^{i\varphi})\rvert\le 1/R^3$. Now estimating the absolut value of the integral yields
$$\left\lvert \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(Re^{i\varphi})iRe^{i\varphi}\,\mathrm{d}\varphi\right\rvert \le \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left\lvert  f(Re^{i\varphi})iRe^{i\varphi}\right\rvert\,\mathrm{d}\varphi\le \frac{2\pi}{R^2}.$$
The same solution can be obtained with the [ML-inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma). Now letting $R\to\infty$ gives that the absolut value of the integral is $\le0$, which obviously implies that the integral is equal to zero.

*Note: Idea was first mentioned by Conrad in the comments.*

Comment: Ok I see thanks!